# Redirecionamento www htaccess com segmento na url

Tags: htaccess, redirect

Onde meu site está hospedado, estou utilizando o .htaccess e nele tem uma condição para remover o www e direcionar para a página principal, sem o www.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

Header set X-Frame-Options DENY

RewriteEngine On

# Required to allow direct-linking of pages so they can be processed by Angular
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://meusite.com.br [R=301,L]

</ifModule>
```

O problema é o seguinte, quando alguém acessa uma página interna com www, ele cai para essa verificação e é direcionado para a home, exemplo:

Caso alguém acessar o link: http://www.meusitecom.br/conteudo/94-vai-criar-um-site-para-a-sua-empresa-saiba-o-que-nao-pode-faltar

Ele irá direcionar para http://meusite.com.br conforme condição.

O que preciso, é que seja direcionado para o seguinte link: http://meusitecom.br/conteudo/94-vai-criar-um-site-para-a-sua-empresa-saiba-o-que-nao-pode-faltar apenas removendo o www do link.

Alguém sabe informar se há a possibilidade desta verificação ser feita no .htaccess?

*Lembrando que quando acessar a interna com www, preciso que seja removido somente o www e não seja redirecionado para a home.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270281/6510304)

Comment: Não funcionou :/ editei a pergunta e inseri o código inteiro do .htaccess

Comment: @MaurícioKrüger tem certeza? Fiz o teste e funcionou. [Link do teste](http://htaccess.mwl.be/?share=8f8699f9-3be2-5c8f-ac7e-53a39bf10912)